# Generating a literal for a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in an INSERT INTO query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am writing a utility, C#, to import a large CSV with about 80 columns into a SQL Server 2008 table.

The CSV needs manipulation before import e.g. merging some columns, converting dates etc.  I am therefore constructing an `INSERT INTO` statement like so:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('abc','blah',...)
```

My problem is that the table contains a column of type `UNIQUEINDENTIFIER`.  It's a problem because I would like to re-use an existing method which takes a collection of values and returns the string of values to pop directly into my `INSERT INTO` statement with apostrophes dealt with, injection attacks munged out etc.

Is there a way of generating a valid literal for a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` that I can pass to this method?  I tried `Guid.NewGuid.ToString()`, which gives me a literal like so `'bfdb0297-2018-4555-ac12-88064944a671'`, but my query then errors with a data truncation exception.  I also tried with the hyphens removed.  I expected 32 hex characters to work.

I know that a parameterised query is the correct way to go but that would mean a significant re-work of existing code.

I'm pretty good with C# and bluff-worthy with SQL Server.

[EDIT]

I've done several things.  First, wrote a query which updates that column with Guid.NewGuid at it works.  Therefore, the truncation error is not from there.  Checking the SQL Server reference leads me to believe that a truncation error is not returned from a bad value in an id column, rather it's an invalid value error.  I've also taken into account Aaron's comment that significant work is not an excuse for not doing it right and have created a method to generate a parameterised query which is now working fine.

Many thanks to all responders.

Comment: Can you show the table structure, an example insert statement that fails, and the exact error message? This works fine for me: `DECLARE @x TABLE(y UNIQUEIDENTIFIER); INSERT @x SELECT 'bfdb0297-2018-4555-ac12-88064944a671';` - my guess is perhaps it is a different column causing the problem, or maybe a trigger.

Comment: Also "amount of work" should not be the highest ranking of criteria for "doing it right"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this works fine:

```sql
DECLARE @x TABLE(y UNIQUEIDENTIFIER); 

INSERT @x SELECT 'bfdb0297-2018-4555-ac12-88064944a671';
```

And this fails with the generic error message that you're currently getting:

```sql
DECLARE @x TABLE
(
  y UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  z CHAR(10)
); 

INSERT @x 
  SELECT 'bfdb0297-2018-4555-ac12-88064944a671',
         '0123456789A';
```

Result:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 7
>  String or binary data would
>   be truncated.
>  The statement has been terminated.

I have to question whether the error is really happening on the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column. I suspect that either (a) the error is happening on a different column in the table, and you haven't verified all of your string lengths, or (b) there is a trigger on the table and the error is happening there.

If you use proper parameters instead of just throwing a string together, you can make sure that each parameter is defined exactly as it is in the table.

Answer (score 20):

A [literal `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/guid-escape-sequences?view=sql-server-ver15) looks like this:

```
SELECT {guid'8DEC377B-6D75-424B-AE01-D3727993C7F6'}
```

As seen in the documentation:

> It is a sequence formed by **the keyword `GUID`** followed by hexadecimal
> digits in the form known as registry format: 8-4-4-4-12 **enclosed in
> single quotes.**

No one seems to know this. This is the first language I have seen that actually has literal GUID/UUIDs.

Comment: This does work, but a documentation link would make me up-vote.

Comment: If anyone needs a GUID generator: https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx

Comment: Excellent, the documentation link not only shows this but also similar prefixes for TIME, DATETIME, and others. Nice!

Comment: The documentation link takes me to a page for something called "Entity SQL", which according to a link on that same page is not the same as T-SQL.

Comment: Note the enclosing `{` and `}` characters are required.

Comment: This type of SQL escape depends on your SQL client/driver. It will work fine from SQLCMD or SSMS or the native .Net clients, but it doesn't work from the jTDS JDBC driver.

Comment: As noted, the documentation you've linked is for Entity SQL, not T-SQL. What you're actually using here is not T-SQL, but an [ODBC Extension called "Guid Escape Sequences"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/guid-escape-sequences?view=sql-server-ver15). That can work in many apps, but I think it's incorrect to characterize it as "a literal UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in SQL Server".

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the SQL INSERT statement? Why not set it to use something specific for that column?

```
xxx, 
xxx,
convert(uniqueidentifier, 'A8AC30E7-B984-4E29-A97A-A434F2B2AB7C'), 
xxx, 
xxx
```